# Pass object attribute from a class to a method of another class

Tags: java, class, object, methods, jframe

I have a problem about passing object attributes from a class to another. I have two class: `AggiungiEs` that is a jframe interface where I can select values through three spinners and assign them to variables,

```
String serie = String.valueOf(spinner.getValue());
String ripetizioni = String.valueOf(spinner_1.getValue());
String recupero = String.valueOf(spinner_2.getValue());
```

then I want to create an object with those variables and pass this object to a second class method that is `addEsercizioScheda`.

```
GestoreEsercizi gE = new GestoreEsercizi();
EsercizioScheda esercizio = new EsercizioScheda(nomeEs, gruppoMuscolare, 
    allenamento, serie, ripetizioni, recupero);
gE.addEsercizioScheda(esercizio, idScheda);
```

The problem is that their value doesn't appear in the second class: when I print them it returns me "null"...

```
public void addEsercizioScheda(EsercizioScheda esercizioScheda, String idScheda) {

        [.......SOME STUFF TO WRITE IN A XML FILE]

    Element IDEsercizio = ultimoElemento.getChild("ID");
    IDEsercizio.setText(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
    Element nodoEsercizi = new Element("Esercizi");
    ultimoElemento.addContent(nodoEsercizi);
    nodoEsercizi.addContent("\n");         // va a capo ad ogni cambio di tag
    Element nodoEsercizioScheda = new Element("EsercizioScheda");
    nodoEsercizi.addContent(nodoEsercizioScheda);
    nodoEsercizioScheda.addContent("\n");         // va a capo ad ogni cambio di tag
    Element nodoIDEsercizioScheda = new Element("ID").setText(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
    nodoEsercizioScheda.addContent(nodoIDEsercizioScheda);
    nodoEsercizioScheda.addContent("\n");
    Element nodoIDAllenamento = new Element("IDAllenamento").setText("DA MODIFICARE");
    nodoEsercizioScheda.addContent(nodoIDAllenamento);
    nodoEsercizioScheda.addContent("\n");         // va a capo ad ogni cambio di tag
    Element nodoSerie = new Element("Serie").setText(esercizioScheda.serie);
    nodoEsercizioScheda.addContent(nodoSerie);
    nodoEsercizioScheda.addContent("\n");         // va a capo ad ogni cambio di tag
    Element nodoRipetizioni = new Element("Ripetizioni").setText(esercizioScheda.ripetizioni);
    nodoEsercizioScheda.addContent(nodoRipetizioni);
    nodoEsercizioScheda.addContent("\n");         // va a capo ad ogni cambio di tag
    Element nodoRecupero = new Element("Recupero").setText(esercizioScheda.recupero);
    nodoEsercizioScheda.addContent(nodoRecupero);
    nodoEsercizioScheda.addContent("\n");         // va a capo ad ogni cambio di tag
    System.out.println(esercizioScheda.serie);

            [....]
```

When I print `esercizioScheda.serie` it returns me "null"... How can I fix it?

Comment: are you sure that String.valueOf(....) returns the right value you expect?

Answer (score 0):

I can't see something wrong with the way you send the object attribute. Can you debug and check what does this return for your serie attribute:

`String serie = spinner.getValue().toString();`